# Regex get all words before a specific word

Tags: c#, regex

I want to get many words as possible before a specific word, but this is getting all characters from all lines.

`([\w\s]+)( Subtract| Add) is (\d+) credits`

If the the line don't match with full expression it's can't be match, why some lines match anyway?

`This line cannot match
This line cannot match too
No way to match
Why is matching this line
Apple Banana Orange Add is 34 credits
Watermelon Strawberry Subtract is 20 credits
Sugar Add is 8 credits`

thats a sample https://regexr.com/3to7l

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that `\s` can match the newlines, and treat the whole of your input as one big match.

To fix your regex :

Replace the first part `[\w\s]+` by `.+`. This will give :

```
(.+)( Subtract| Add) is (\d+) credits
```

see here : 
[RegexStorm working example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.%2b%29%28+Subtract%7c+Add%29+is+%28%5cd%2b%29+credits&i=This+line+cannot+match%0d%0a%0d%0aThis+line+cannot+match+too%0d%0aNo+way+to+match%0d%0aWhy+is+matching+this+line%0d%0aApple+Banana+Orange+Add+is+34+credits%0d%0aWatermelon+Strawberry+Subtract+is+20+credits%0d%0aSugar+Add+is+8+credits%0d%0a&o=m)

Note : this actually changes a bit your intent, because non-word and non-space characters can now be matched by `.+`. If this is a problem, you might want to use `^`, `$`, `\A` or `\Z` .

See here for more info, for instance : https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/46/c-regular-expressions-cheat-sheet

or https://download.microsoft.com/download/D/2/4/D240EBF6-A9BA-4E4F-A63F-AEB6DA0B921C/Regular%20expressions%20quick%20reference.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can use this RegEx:

```
.*(?: Subtract| Add) is \d+ credits
```

and you can test it [here](http://bak-o-soft.dk/RegEx/RegExBuilder.aspx)